# Collision between RigidBody2D and TileMap Collider 2D not working on build (but working on inspector)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey I'm starting to loose my mind over this issue.

I have a RigidBody 2D (my player) that **collide perfectly fine when I hit play in the inspector** with a TileMap Collider 2D (the floor of the map) but **not at all in the build** (with the run and build option). It just go through the floor like it hasn't any collider.

*The RigidBody:*
[image]

*The TileMap Collider 2D:*
[image]

I have tried to run the build in "Development build" mode to see some logs but there is nothing there.

I'm on unity 2019.3.0.0f1. I'm building for windows x64 standalone.

I'm out of ideas at this point, so I'll appreciate a lot if you had a lead for me :)

(If you need additionnal screenshots or info tell me I'll update the question)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay although I don't really understand why I foun da solution to my problem.

I simply changed the Composite Collider 2D "Generation Type" of the Map to "Manual"

[image: screenshot]

If someone understand why the default "Synchronous" was not working I'd be happy to know...

Answer (score 1):

1. Try use collision detection - continuous in rigidbody2d for player;
2. Try use this settings in "Player Settings", i had same issue but with raycast;
3. Check layer collision mask;
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQFjm.png)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I'm already using detection continuous on the player (cf the screenshoton the question)

And I tried your setting but unfortunatly I have the same issue: https://imgur.com/gallery/utTZCHr